# ruby dbi mysql connection

Tags: mysql, ruby, dbi

I am able to connect to MySQL database using `host=127.0.0.1`:

```
>> require 'dbi'
=> true
>> DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306", "root", "password")
=> #<DBI::DatabaseHandle:0x2ae4378 @handle=#<DBI::DBD::Mysql::Database:0x2ae44f8
 @handle=#<Mysql:0x2ae4600>, @attr={"AutoCommit"=>true}, @have_transactions=true
, @mutex=#<Mutex:0x2ae4390>>, @trace_output=nil, @trace_mode=nil, @convert_types
=true, @driver_name="Mysql">
```

But when I try to connect the same database server with `host=localhost`, It gives me error:

```
>> DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:host=localhost;port=3306", "root", "password")
DBI::DatabaseError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbd-mysql-0.4.4/lib/dbd/Mysql.r
b:106:in `error'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbd-mysql-0.4.4/lib/dbd/mysql/d
river.rb:70:in `rescue in connect'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbd-mysql-0.4.4/lib/dbd/mysql/d
river.rb:32:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/drive
r.rb:33:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:148:in `co
nnect'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

So what is the reason it is not working and should I check if localhost is provided in the host option, it should be converted to 127.0.0.1 and then connect to the database..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IPV6? On those machines localhost resolves to ::1

Do a "ping localhost" to see what exactly is going on.

It looks like when you specify "localhost" the library is trying to use the local socket

according to some docs
socket=path_name
The pathname of the Unix socket file, for localhost connections. So it looks like you need to add the path of the socket